# MacOS: Check if a keyboard shortcut conflicts with a system shortcut

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

Stack: Native MacOS app, using SwiftUI

Is there a way to check if a keyboard shortcut conflicts with a system shortcut?

```
func isKeyboardShortcutReservedForSystemShortcut(key: KeyEquivalent, modifiers: EventModifiers) -> Bool {
    // Return `true` if there is already a system shortcut with the given key and modifiers
}
```

Some use cases:

1. Conditionally add the `keyboardShortcut` modifier to Button views
2. I want to make app shortcuts configurable, and I would show a warning when a configured shortcut conflicts with a system shortcut

Comment: Apple prefers the system key commands, if you didnt knew. This is an important information.

When using SwiftUi, you can do a lot with the .keyboardShortcut modifier...
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/keyboardshortcut

For usecase 1 an example:

    VStack {
    Button("Start me") {
        print("Starting…")
    }
    .keyboardShortcut("s", modifiers: .shift)

    Button("Clean something") {
        print("Cleaning")
    }
    .keyboardShortcut("c", modifiers: [.control, .option, .command])
    }

Comment: Hi @Iskandir, thank you, I am already familiar with the `.keyboardShortcut` modifier. My question is about how to check whether a key + modifier combination is already used by a system shortcut, so that I know I should not use it for a keyboardShortcut in my app.

Comment: Yeah, I understand your question but I dont have an answer to your question - i just wanted to help you with some information :)